# Print settings in AutoCAD

Tags: printing, autocad, dimensions

I wanted to know how to print the AutoCAD file so that only the numbers displayed in the DIMENSIONS and the DIMENSION'S lines are not displayed.
And how to increase the size of the DIMENSION'S text.
I do not know much about English, so I would apologize if I wrote a mistake. Thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not anyone understand me? Or was there no answer to my question?
If you've used SolidWorks before, you might have seen that when you want to print a map or project, there is an option available, which if you select it, the DIMENSION lines will hide, but their numbers will still be displayed.
I mean, this is such a feature for AutoCAD. Is AutoCAD Capable? How to use this feature?